# GWT plugin for Eclipse not downloading

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm following the [Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) Installation Instructions](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.5.html).

During downloading I get the following error in Eclipse 3.5 Galileo, is the jar file corrupt on the server corrupt or what? Is it possible to manually import the GWT plugin in Eclipse?

```
java.io.IOException: Error unzipping C:\DOCUME~1\Imran\LOCALS~1\Temp\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.0_2.0.0.v2009120620038443413526480826930.jar: invalid entry size (expected 18889986 but got 18889962 bytes)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.helpers.FileUtils.unzipFile(FileUtils.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository$ZippedFolderOutputStream.close(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:155)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository$ArtifactOutputStream.close(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a manual install via the `dropins` folder: http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html
But make sure you don't have any old versions of the plugin first.

Comment: Well I`m trying this for the first time, I hope all this effort is worth it, let check that link, 

thanks mate!

Comment: I download the zip file, now imgetting a CRC error on this, what the hell is wrong with this world?

!   E:\gpe-e35-latest.zip: CRC failed in eclipse\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.core_1.2.0.v200912062003.jar. The file is corrupt

Comment: Wow, that is really bizarre - I just downloaded the file, unzipped it and it seems just fine. The CRC32 of the zip file is `539E523C`, MD5 `1a97e973163644bfc10143f4a6edff32`, and the CRC32 values of the contents of the zip file are here: http://pastebin.com/m2417e1b5. If you have the same checksums, then it would suggest a deeper problem - something with your OS, zip program, maybe even hardware.